# IE7 positioned element hides behind parent

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I'm struggling to get the CSS right for IE7 and I hope someone here can give me a hand before I throw my pc out the window :p

I made a fiddle that shows what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZqkEE/

The div with the word "joepie" hides behind the image in IE7.

How do I fix this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the text is not shown at all in IE7. If you remove the img-tag, you'll see that the text is not under the image, it's actually not there at all.. Not quite sure why it's not there but here's some suggestions: There's no specified left-attribute, that might be it? Or maybe IE7 doesn't like the bottom-attribute?

I'm no IE7 expert, but I hope I pointed you in the right direction! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Couple things here. You have a height of 1 on intro and a line-height of 0 on the .wrp div. Also, the entire .intro div was being pushed off to the right. I added a left property and it moved back into place - [jsfiddle.net/Rpjhc/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/Rpjhc/2/)